# UnrealEngine4 - Interactive 360 picture

Tags: unreal-engine4

I have very little experience with UnrealEngine (just a basic handling of the menues as I played around a bit creating levels back in the day) and also have an Oculus DK2 to test out VR. Is it possible to create a UE Scene that displays a 360 picture, and then add "hotspots" to the picture that trigger voiceovers or even text messages on the screen?.

Basically the client wants to Demo their room and add commentary to specific items within the scene, but they do not have the resources for hiring 3D modelers. So they would settle for a static room (picture) where you can just look around (obviously not walk) and trigger some events depending on where you look.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, or enlighten me that this is not possible?

Answer (score 1):

What you suggest sounds plausible - though it is not going to be easy under a tight deadline.  Unreal Engine 4 is quite a bit different from 3 and earlier.

You also can get access to the C++ Source now via github when you register.

Take a look at the [official best practices](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Platforms/VR/ContentSetup/) and the sample links off that to see if you can get that running on your development kit.  That will at least give you an idea of what you are up against.